# OnClientClick is stopping postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a set of ASP.NET controls:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Find"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    runat="server"
    CausesValidation="true"
    OnClientClick="$('#Find').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); $('#SearchingLabel').show();">
    <span>Search</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="SearchingLabel"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    runat="server"
    Text="Searching..."
    style="display: none;" />
```

and as you can see I'm consuming the `OnClientClick` so that I can disable the `Find` button and show the `SearchingLabel` (**and the JavaScript works without error BTW**). Pretty basic stuff.

Further, surrounding the `CausesValidation` attribute, I do have validation controls on the page, but there are no current validation errors.

However, even though I'm not returning `false` from the JavaScript the page **isn't posting back**. I've even attempted to `return true;` but that didn't change anything (*not really that surprising but it was worth a try*).

I look forward to your feedback!

Comment: The `CausesValidation="true"`? Do you have ValidationControls on your page? Those could cause it

Comment: @codingbiz, I do have validation controls on the page, but there are no validation errors.

Comment: This can also occur if you remove the control or the parent control of the control that you are posting back with, something like `OnClientClick="$(this).remove()"` will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are disabling your button, before the postback.

You could try your page/script without the disabling part in it:

```
OnClientClick="$('#SearchingLabel').show();"
```

If this works, try it with a short delay:

```
OnClientClick="setTimeout(function() { $('#Find').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }, 100); $('#SearchingLabel').show();"
```

Comment: Okay, so removing the `disabled` jQuery works and causes it to postback again. However, the `setTimeout` causes unexpected side effects in that not only does the button never disable (e.g. if I put a `Thread.Sleep` for five seconds server-side) but the `SearchingLabel` doesn't show **even if I put that line *before* the `setTimeout`**.

Comment: I didn't see this one coming... Did you correct my typo in your code? I typed "funtion" instead of "function", will edit my answer.

Comment: That's all it was. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this js code onload

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequest);
function BeginRequest(sender, e) {
    e.get_postBackElement().disabled = true;
    // or your code

}
function EndRequest(sender, e) {
   .......
}
```