# ASP.Net button Disable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I am disabling the button using the javascript code but my server side event is not firing..Any idea?

```
Javascript
------------------------

        function DisableButton() {
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                Page_ClientValidate();
            }
            if (Page_IsValid) {
               document.getElementById('<%=BtnToprimaryValidation.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('<%=BtnToprimaryValidation.ClientID%>').value = 'Please wait ...';
            }
        }

ASP.Net
-------------------------
<asp:Button ID="BtnToprimaryValidation" runat="server" 
                        meta:resourcekey="BtnToprimaryValidationResource1" 
                       CssClass="submitButton">

Server Side c#
---------------------------

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnToprimaryValidation.Click += BtnToprimaryValidationClick;
        }
         protected void BtnToprimaryValidationClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Thanks in Advance,
Rahul R

Answer (score 0):

**Events do not fire on disabled items**

Instead of disabling, you'll have to change your `DisableButton` method to `return false`, like so:

```
function DisableButton() {
        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            Page_ClientValidate();
        }
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            document.getElementById('<%=BtnToprimaryValidation.ClientID%>').value = 'Please wait ...';
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous answer by [@mattytommo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo), **events do not fire on disabled buttons**.

Use a short timeout to fire the event first and then disable the button:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
document.getElementById('<%=BtnToprimaryValidation.ClientID%>').disabled = true; 
}, 100);
```

Just like I suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195881/onclientclick-is-stopping-postback).