# Prevent JavaScript OnClick binded confirm() to override VB.NET Click handler

Tags: javascript, vb.net, event-handling

I have to resolve a problem in some code assigned to me and the problem is that following <strike>this code in `page.init`</strike> `else` statemant:

```
Me.SaveChangesButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", 
    "if (!confirm('Are you sure?')){
        return false;
     } else {
        document.getElementById('SaveChangesButton').disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById('rejectButton').disabled = true;
     }
")
```

overrides this code:

```
Protected Sub SaveChangesButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChangesButton.Click
```

### Question [edited]

1. <strike>How can I bind `confirm()` to button so that it doesn't override my `handler` function?</strike>
2. <strike>Where in the code would it be best practice to bind it?</strike>
3. <strike>If I remove second part `else {document.getElementById('SaveChangesButton').disabled = 
   true; document.getElementById('rejectButton').disabled = true;}` it works correctly, but how should I write it so it continues to execute `SaveChangesButton_Click`, as I understand only the second part overrides handler?</strike>
4. **How can I execute those two lines** `document.getElementById('SaveChangesButton').disabled = true; 
           document.getElementById('rejectButton').disabled = true;` **and still execute** `SaveChangesButton_Click` **handler without overriding it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
Me.SaveChangesButton.OnClientClick = @"
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('SaveChangesButton').disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById('rejectButton').disabled = true;
    }"
```

2) If you bind the `SaveChangesButton_Click` in the `Page.Init`, I would then set the `OnClientClick` too.

3,4) The `OnClientClick` fires (sort of) before the server side `OnClick` (of course). This makes you disabling your button, before firing the `OnClick`. And `OnClick` won't fire on a disabled button. What to do? **Delay disabling your button**.

```
Me.SaveChangesButton.OnClientClick = @"
if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    return false;
} else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('SaveChangesButton').disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById('rejectButton').disabled = true;
    }, 100);
}"
```

And this actually makes your question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195881/onclientclick-is-stopping-postback)...

Comment: Thanks, just tested works fine. But still using `timeout` feels wrong.

Comment: As soon as you find another way, please post it as an answer. I'll be very interested.